# Does core of a proton exist?

Tags: nuclear-physics, standard-model, protons

I understand a proton is made up of quarks/gluons. I want to know if a proton has an actual core? Also whether protons have a core/surface temperature.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What's inside a proton?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/81190/)

Comment: Thank you, David Z's answer covers my question quite well, I was trying to relate a proton to a hypothetical "quark star".

Comment: Welcome! That answer is quite great.