# What is the shape of the quark structure in a proton or neutron?

Tags: particle-physics, standard-model, quarks, protons

I know the pictures we see are just a representation to help people understand what is going on while in reality the quark is likely a wave vs a particle. That being said it is always depicted as a triangle arrangement when I would have figured a more linear structure due to same charges repulsing each other while the opposite charge attracting the other two quarks.

Something like this,
(-)(+)(-) or (+)(-)(+)

Comment: Possible duplicate:  https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/81190/2451

Comment: Interesting question, I would expect something like orbitals or similar as the answer. But I guess nobody can tell because even confinement is not so well unterstood and also the yang-mills field of SU(3) has to many degrees of freedom to be visualized easily.

Comment: Take look at this website: https://profmattstrassler.com/articles-and-posts/particle-physics-basics/the-structure-of-matter/protons-and-neutrons/