# What is the volume of electron?

Tags: quantum-mechanics

I know that electron has mass , and that is particle( a body which has only mass and whose size is negligible) but can we ever calculate the volume of the electron . if yes how much it is . if no why?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the mass density distribution of an electron?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/24001/)

Comment: I don't know : the technical level of the question is not the same, even if the physical content is.

Comment: i am sorry , i didn't know about it . thank you for the guidance