# Point-like particle vs naked singularity?

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, singularities, point-particles

In general, physics seems to consider elementary particles such as electrons to be point-like. On the other hand, naked singularities seem to cause all sorts of trouble, including closed time-like curves, and are generally considered to be non-physical.

What is the exact difference between a point-like particle (eg electron as we know it) and a naked singularity (eg black hole electron), and why exactly considering a particle point-like is ok, while considering it to be superextremal black hole is not?

Comment: See https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/165823/133418 and https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/75911/133418

Comment: Your question apparently assumes that a singularity is a point in space, but it is not.

Comment: I checked the questions linked above, and while relevant and interesting, they do not seem to explain why point particles do not have the same non-physicality issues as superextremal black holes. I am not sure how to address this in the question more precisely...

Comment: With naked singularities you loose predictability. No such problem with point particles.