# Is it almost impossible to separate two point charges stuck together?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electrostatics, singularities, coulombs-law

$$F=k\frac{qQ}{r^2},$$ if $r\rightarrow 0$ then $F\rightarrow \infty$.

Comment: If the electromagnetic force were the only force acting, and the points have zero size, then yes. But that's not the universe we live in.

Comment: The electron is not a point particle. It has a wave nature. See answers like [this](http://physics.stackexchange.com/a/221679/76162).

Comment: As others have hinted, classical E&M has this embarrassing flaw: divergences at every point particle!  To study interactions as r->0 requires a more sophisticated picture than classical E&M

Comment: "Hey, can you get that Pauli guy on the phone? My hydrogen's gone inert again."