Is There a Peculiarity in the Wave-Particle Behavior of Electrons in CRT TVs?
As seen in the illustration, the Electron Gun appears to fire particles at the target. However, shouldn’t these particles also behave like waves? How is it possible to direct a wave precisely to a specific target point?

The part that’s mind-boggling to me is the concept of the ‘gun.’
In a bullet gun, it shoots individual bullets. So, shouldn’t an electron gun similarly shoot individual electrons?

What is the issue here? The electron wave spread is vanishingly small compared to the circuitry of a television…

Have you not seen a concentrated, small, beam of light?

We focus waves to a point all the time. Why would electron waves be different?

@MattHanson So, as far as I understand, the electron gun shoots waves rather than individual electrons. Is that correct?

Regarding the comments, I improved my question by the way.

maybe my answer here will help https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/221656/the-size-of-an-electron

An electron is a wave. It is also a particle. Quantum is weird.
