# Does the electron charge rotate faster than its mass?

Tags: particle-physics, electrons, quantum-spin, quantum-electrodynamics, spin-models

The electron has a g-factor given by $g/2 = 1 + \alpha / 2\pi$ .

Does the expression really mean that the charge of the electron rotates faster than its mass - if they have the same distribution?

Comment: Related: [Classical proof of the gyromagnetic ratio g=2](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/224675).

Answer (score 1):

Both the spin angular momentum and the magnetic moment of the electron are quantum properties of the particle which are not related to a rotation of mass or charge as one would expect for a classical object.