# Are quarks the densest "objects" in the universe?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, mass, density, quarks

My reasoning is that all matter is made of quarks + the space in between them. So therefore, among matter, a single quark should be the densest object. I'm not sure for non-matter though; I'm also not sure about singularities.

Comment: Black holes are denser.  Possible duplicate: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/24001/44126

Answer (score 1):

[This is the table](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/0/00/Standard_Model_of_Elementary_Particles.svg/375px-Standard_Model_of_Elementary_Particles.svg.png) of elementary particles of the Standard Model of particle physics.

All these particles are point particles, and in a mathematical sense, the fact that many of them  are assigned a mass would be considered as a singularity in density, but that is not the way it happens in the microcosm of quantum mechanics. The concept of mass density has no meaning for single particles ,in a framework where everything is described by a probability and in addition is ruled by [quantum mechanics laws.](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/quantum/qm.html)