# How is the mass of an electron distributed?

Tags: quantum-mechanics

Since the position of an electron is not determined, how is it’s mass distributed ? In other words, how does an electron curve space time ?

.

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/119732/2451 and links therein.

Comment: Actually [this one](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/24001/21441) is even closer to the wording of this question.