# Is electron a matter?

Tags: electrons, definition, matter, subatomic

I know electrons are subatomic particles which make up atoms, the building blocks of [matter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matter). But is electron a matter itself? Moreover, are atoms or quantum particles matter too considering their particle nature for now?

Comment: Except for massless particles like photons, every other particle and their combination is called matter.

Comment: whyd don't you look up the definition of  "matter" in wikipedia, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matter

Answer (score 1):

As Wikipedia says:

*In classical physics and general chemistry, matter is any substance
that has mass and takes up space by having volume.*

Electrons are fermions, that is, [elementary particles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_particle), that is, with no substructure.

A [point particle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_particle) is different from an elementary particle :

*In quantum mechanics, the concept of a point particle is complicated by the Heisenberg uncertainty principle, because even an elementary particle, with no internal structure, occupies a nonzero volume.*

Therefore, **electrons have mass and volume, hence electrons are matter.**

Comment: I like your logic, but I think using the H.U.P. to assert that electrons *have* volume is a stretch. The quote you present asserts that electrons *occupy* a volume, which could mean a few different things depending on your your philosophical interpretation of quantum mechanics. It does not guarantee that electrons are not point particles with zero size that simply have a specific volume associated with the probability of locating them. If the electron actually possesses a nonzero volume like you assert, we would be able to assign a mass density to it. I am not aware of such a thing.

Comment: Here thread that shines light on whether an electron can be said to have a mass density/occupy a volume. The answer is if the electron does have a radius, it is not bigger than $10^{-22}$, and it behaves as a point particle in every experiment to date. https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/24001/139376 I think ultimately the answer to whether an electron is "matter" is an issue of semantics. I think we can all agree the electron is a "matter particle" or "particle of matter" (unlike the photon).

Answer (score 0):

Light (photons) doesn't have a mass.
Particles that move slower than light have a property called rest mass.
These particles can exist without moving around.
But they still  have energy given by Einstein's famous equation E=mc^2.
Light waves with enough energy can crash into a sheet of lead and change into
positive and negative charges with mass like electrons and positrons. By Einstein's equation light energy becomes mass.
A useful way to think of energy and mass is that energy is water vapour and mass is drops of water. They are the same and different.