# Difference between electrons from atoms of different elements?

Tags: electrons

Is there is any difference between electrons from different elements?

Comment: Why do you think there is a difference between them?

Comment: It is a fairly fundamental principle in QM that electrons cannot be distinguished. So, while electrons captured by hydrogen or carbon might be in a different energy state, as electrons they are identical.

Comment: @Physics_Et_AL I'm just trying to understand the flow of electrons through conductors and how a chemical reaction in a battery drives the electron movement and I was wondering if at all there could is any difference between electrons from different metals then how it is passing between different metals. Thanks!

Comment: The difference would not be of the electrons but the physical dynamics of the electrons in the different metals due to different potential energy environment of the solids. For instance, the electrons in a metal are in a different set of potential energy environment than in the semi-conductors or insulators. It is this that determines their conductance behavior and not the type of electron. For electrons: *If you have seen one, you've seen 'em all!*

Answer (score -3, accepted):

All electrons are the same, they have a mass $m = 9.1\times10^{-31}$ kg and a charge $e =1.6\times10^{-19}$ C. Imagine them as small rotating balls that are here and there at a moment in time and later (the many universes image of the world), imagine them as a cloud in the atom (the quantum mechanics image of the world) . :)

Comment: It's generally *not* helpful to think of electrons as little spinning balls. Please see https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/119732/123208 An electron has spin, but it doesn't have components that spin around a central axis.

Comment: Have you read about the Multiverse image on the world, ,please? About the Bohmian quantum mechanics?  An electron can be a rotating ball in the Bohmian quantum mechanics or a cloud in the classical quantum mechanics.

Comment: What do you mean? Google says: *No results found for "Multiverse image on the world".* I am a little familiar with Bohmian mechanics, and various multiverse theories. But I don't see the connection with modeling electrons as little spinning balls.

Comment: Electrons have a component (in some sense a `degree of freedom' ) in their wave function that can be called spin. One can imagine this to be analogous to a sphere spinning about its axis. However, this analogy can only be taken so far and is not a reflection of reality.  Electrons are, as far as the standard (i.e. the accepted) model of quantum field theory can tell, truly point-like particles so they really can't spin about an axis. As for Bohmian mechanics, I'd have to read up on it and it would take a lot of technical work to really understand what it says about electrons and their spin.