# What is the smallest particle? What is the building block of an electron?

Tags: particle-physics, electrons, elementary-particles, point-particles

I'm curious.

Why when I was 5 years old did I rip things apart in half... Always trying to get another half... is it endless?

I took a leaf and ripped it in half, and kept on going...

God?

Comment: Wave length and energy comes to my mind. The smaller the scale, the higher the energy. That is one problem in producing chips with smaller structures. The light of the lasers used must be of higher frequency and higher energy.

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/119732/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/24001/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/277565/2451 and links therein.

Answer (score 2):

Electrons are fundamental. They have no internal components, no building blocks. They are point particles, they have infinitesimally small size. There are other fundamental particles. These are the quarks, the other leptons (muon and tau), the neutrinos, gauge bosons, and the Higgs boson.

There are some hypotheses that claim the particles listed above are not fundamental and are composed of smaller components, but none have been confirmed. One prominent such hypothesis is string theory, which proposes that all of these particles are composed of a kind of 1 dimensional string vibrating in 10+ dimensions.