# Do charges have spatial dimension?

Tags: electrostatics, charge, elementary-particles, point-particles

I don't know much about anything in physics. I hope you can bear with that. Let me start with my question do charges have any dimension, by this I mean physical dimension like length, breadth, height or something like that. But here in some textbooks we learn something else which comes from nowhere. If it were some 2 dimensional property how would it emit an electric field in 3 dimension?  Or what exactly is a charge?

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/24001/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/119732/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/277565/2451 and links therein.

Answer (score 0):

Charge is a property of elemental particles, such as electrons and quarks, just like mass is. Two objects with mass attract eachother with the gravitational force and two charged objects attract or repel eachother with the electric (Lorentz-) force $F_{\rm el}=Eq$, induced by the electric field $E$ between the charged objects. I don't understand what you mean by a property of a particle having a dimension. I don't think it does.

Comment: A subatomic particles is associated with a wave packet, and its possible that its energy, charge, and mass are distributed throughout the (variable) volume of the packet.

Comment: I don't think @shanmu383 wants to go into QM...