# Size of electron?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, particle-physics, electrons, elementary-particles, point-particles

It is claimed that the electron has a size less than $10^{-19}$m. I presume this is based on high-energy scattering experiments.

But isn’t this apparent size simply a function of the high energy of the particle used to perform the scattering experiment?

As the target electron is scattered it will have a lot of uncertainty in its momentum and therefore will be well localized. But this length scale has nothing to do with the intrinsic size of a target electron at rest.

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/24001/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/119732/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/277565/2451 and links therein.