# Is there a shape associated to point charge?

Tags: electrostatics, electrons, charge, symmetry, point-particles

This is puzzling to me because I have learnt that a charged sphere has the same electric field and electric potential at a point beyond its surface. So does it mean that a point charge is also inherently a sphere?

Comment: How about the surface areas of the sphere vs the point charge? What does inherently mean?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/24001/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/119732/2451 and links therein.

Answer (score 0):

We can write any electric field as the sum of the fields from a monopole, a dipole, a quadrupole and so on up to whatever number of higher poles we need. This is known as a [multipole expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multipole_expansion). Any we can, mathematically at least, have a point monopole, a point dipole, a point quadrupole, and so on.

However when we use the term *point charge* we are normally specifically referring to a monopole, and not to any of the higher poles. The monopole field is spherically symmetric so it is the same as the field outside a sphere. However this does not mean a point charge is a tiny sphere. In fact I would put it the other way round - a point charge is a monopole and a charged sphere has the same field as a point charge because it has the same symmetry as the point charge.

Whether point charges actually exist depends on what exactly you mean by point charge. An electron [is often described as a point](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/277565/where-is-the-evidence-that-the-electron-is-pointlike), and that would make it a point charge. However note that the magnetic field of that electron is a point dipole so a point does not have to be a monopole.